# Material TextInputLayout set two end icons

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I'm trying to add a second `endIcon` to `Material TextInputLayout` like so:

[image]

But feels like it's almost impossible, I've already tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555769/adding-two-end-icons-to-textinputlayout-in-android) but it's not working (at least for me).

Right now I've just a simple TextInputLayout with only one icon (toggle password), and I've no idea how to add a second one like at the screenshot above.

Do you have and advices?

Thanks:)

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tilPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/ed_password_label"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
    app:errorEnabled="true">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: The solution you provided seems like a way to go if you desperately need to implement two end icons. Can you show us how did you tried to implement that solution?